# Error inflating class TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext

I'm trying to use TextInputEditText in my XML, and I'm meeting this error :

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: 
Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/thanhnguyen.com.familysharinglocation-
1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app/thanhnguyen.com.familysharinglocation-1/lib/arm64, 
/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Here my xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:hint="@string/fullName"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

My dependency :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Comment: put your activity code here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to using the support library version which is >= 24.1.0 because `TextInputEditText` is added in version `24.1.0`. Read more at [TextInputEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html)

So, you can use the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added `support design` dependency first in build.gradle

Copy this TextInputLayout in your xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/userPhoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/whiteTextColor"
                >
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/silveryBackground"
                    android:hint="@string/enterMobileNumber"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:paddingLeft="17dp"
                    android:paddingRight="17dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/whiteTextColor"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: No need to do anything just give point to point answer. point to point answer is : just replace  android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText with EditText

Comment: "added support design dependency first"... Order doesn't matter

Comment: @cricket_007 He already added added support design dependency. No need to tell him to add again.

Comment: @cricket_007 what should be version?

Comment: [Search the page for "Added In"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html) @Ajeetyadav

Comment: @Ajeetyadav don't comment wrong. if you have no idea about question don't give comment on others answer